# Getting Currency Multiplication Factor defined in rules in template.php or other block etc

Tags: commerce

I have a rule setup for converting INR to USD using IP to Country module as follows.

```
{ "rules_convert_to_usd" : {
    "LABEL" : "Convert to USD",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "ip2country", "commerce_line_item", "commerce_product_reference" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_product_calculate_sell_price" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "ip2country_user_country" : { "countries" : { "value" : { "US" : "US" } } } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "commerce_line_item_unit_price_multiply" : {
          "commerce_line_item" : [ "commerce_line_item" ],
          "amount" : "0.025",
          "component_name" : "base_price",
          "round_mode" : "1"
        }
      },
      { "commerce_line_item_unit_price_currency_code" : {
          "commerce_line_item" : [ "commerce_line_item" ],
          "currency_code" : "USD"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now I want to get that multiplication factor(.025 in this case) in some custom template view pages, Is that possible?